# D3 Help me animate this Hexagon please

Tags: d3.js

I want to animate the drawing of this Hexagon. First time using D3 still trying to figure out how it works.

jsfiddle.net/p4ezs3ar/

Comment: Please don't change your question so that it invalidates the existing answer. Ask another question instead if you need to. You can always reference this question in that new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Animating it is kind of a trick using the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset svg attributes.

Basically you find the length of your line using

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
```

Then you create a dashed line that is twice the size of your path, half of it is dashed, the other empty.

```
attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
```

Finally, you'll animate it. Start with an offset the size of the totalLength. This is the clear part of your dashed line:

```
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
```

End your animation at 0 so that only the filled part of your dash line is shown:

```
.attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0)
```

Code snippet:

```js
var _s32 = (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
var A = 55;
var diff = 100;
var pointData = [
  [105+diff, 10+diff],
  [25+diff, 60+diff],
  [25+diff, 150+diff],
  [100+diff, 190+diff],
  [175+diff,150+diff],
  [175+diff,60+diff],
  [95+diff, 10+diff]
];
var svgContainer = d3.select("#animation") //create container
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 1000)
  .attr("height", 1000);
var line = d3.svg.line()
 .interpolate('linear')
  .x(function(d,i) { return d[0];})
  .y(function(d) { return d[1];});
  
var path = svgContainer.append('path')
 .attr('d', line(pointData))
  .attr('stroke', '#92c8a1')
  .attr('stroke-width', '22')
  .attr('fill', 'none');

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease("linear")
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

svgContainer.on("click", function(){
  path      
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .ease("linear")
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.10/d3.min.js"></script>

<div id="animation"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you helped me big time. @drinck  I have 1 more question if you can check it here you can see how i coded the situation and what i have and what is the desired hexagon. http://i68.tinypic.com/5jy1xe.jpg  ,  http://i68.tinypic.com/5jy1xe.jpg  Do you think this can be done with d3